# Запрет на обновление фрагмента и переменных в нем

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragment

Есть на котлине какой-то метод, позволяющий запретить обновление фрагмента и его переменных? Суть в том, что при запуска определенного фрагмента у меня идёт передача данных из другого фрагмента, с помощью bundle. И фрагмент по какой-то непонятной пока мне причине прогоняет функции в классе по 2 раза. И данные, которые передаются из предыдущего фрагмента обнуляются.

```
class MapTaskFragment : BaseFragment(), TasksListView {
    override val layoutId: Int
        get() = R.layout.fragment_map_task

    @InjectPresenter
    lateinit var presenter: TasksListPresenter

    private var needUpdate = false

    @ProvidePresenter
    fun initPresenter(): TasksListPresenter = providePresenter()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        println("onViewC")
    }

    private fun initRecycler() {
        println("initRe")
        refresh.setOnClickListener {
            presenter.onRefresh()
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (needUpdate) {
            presenter.onRefresh()
            needUpdate = false
        }
        println("onRes")
    }


    poverride fun onMapping() {
        var bundle = this.arguments
        var urlLast = bundle?.getString("name")
        if (bundle?.getString("name") != null) {
            urlLast = bundle?.getString("name")!!
        }
        println("onMapp")



        println("Зашел в субмит:")

        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.userAgentString =
            "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

        webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(
                origin: String,
                callback: GeolocationPermissions.Callback
            ) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false)
            }
        }
        webView.loadUrl(urlLast)
        println("Тест = $urlLast")
        webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
    }


    override fun submitList(list: List<UiTask>) {
        println("onSubmit")

    }

    override fun setRefreshing(flag: Boolean) {
        println("onSetref")

    }

    override fun startSoundNotification() {
        val uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
        val player = MediaPlayer.create(context, uri)
        player.start()
        println("startSound")

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            view: WebView,
            request: WebResourceRequest
        ): Boolean {
            view.loadUrl(request.url.toString())
            return true
        }

        // Для старых устройств
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            view: WebView,
            url: String
        ): Boolean {
            view.loadUrl(url)
            return true
        }
    }


    override fun onCreateView(

        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?

    ): View? { //Загружаем разметку из XML
        val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false)
        //Находим WebView и загружаем что-нибудь
        val webView = v.findViewById(R.id.webView) as WebView
        return v

    }


    override val actualPresenter: BasePresenter<*>?
        get() = null

    companion object {
        fun getInstance() = MapTaskFragment()

    }
}
```

Вот так прописано во View файле:

```
   @StateStrategyType(AddToEndSingleStrategy::class)
fun onMapping()

@StateStrategyType(OneExecutionStateStrategy::class)
fun submitList(list: List<UiTask>)

@StateStrategyType(AddToEndSingleStrategy::class)
fun setRefreshing(flag: Boolean)

@StateStrategyType(OneExecutionStateStrategy::class)
fun startSoundNotification()
```

Comment: без кода, мы ничем вам помочь не можем

Comment: @danilshik добавил

Comment: ну и где onMapping() вызывается?

Comment: @danilshik прошу прощения, правлю код, сейчас здесь дополнил

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функции выполняются 2 раза подряд](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1132286/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4)

Answer (score 0):

Не думаю, что такое существует, единственный способ сделать все переменные Immutable, то есть нужно отказаться от инжекта значений на поле и делать это через конструктор или через сеттер и объявить все переменные которые не должны меняться через val.