# Функции выполняются 2 раза подряд

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Возникла проблема: написал новый класс, при переходе на фрагмент, функции выполняются 2 раза. В том числе 2 раза выполняется onViewCreated. В чем может быть проблема? 
То что выполняется 2 раза проверил в логах и выводя println. Ниже код onViewCreated:

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    initRecycler()
    onMapping()
    startSoundNotification()
    println("onViewC")
}
```

Пример функции, которая выполняется 2 раза:

```
override fun onMapping() {
    var bundle = this.arguments
    var urlLast = bundle?.getString("name")
    if (bundle?.getString("name") != null) {
        urlLast = bundle?.getString("name")!!
    }
    println("onMapp")



    println("Зашел в субмит:")

    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webView.settings.userAgentString =
        "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

    webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(
            origin: String,
            callback: GeolocationPermissions.Callback
        ) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false)
        }
    }
    webView.loadUrl(urlLast)
    println("Тест = $urlLast")
    webView.webViewClient = MyWebViewClient()
}
```

Вызываю фрагмент отсюда:

```
override fun setRoute(list: List<TaskRouteItem>) {


        for (route in list.withIndex()) {


            when (route.index) {
                0 -> {
                    lineUp.visibility = GONE
                    lineDown.visibility = VISIBLE
                    divider.visibility = VISIBLE
                }
                in 1..list.size - 2 -> {
                    lineUp.visibility = VISIBLE
                    lineDown.visibility = VISIBLE
                    divider.visibility = VISIBLE
                }
                list.size - 1 -> {
                    lineUp.visibility = VISIBLE
                    lineDown.visibility = GONE
                    address.updatePadding(bottom = dpToPx(13))
                    divider.visibility = GONE
                }
            }

            var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient =
                context?.let { LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(it) }!!

            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                    var latitudeF = location?.latitude
                    var longitudeF = location?.longitude



                }

            arrow.setOnClickListener {


                        val i = Bundle()
                        i.putString("name", "${route.value.latitude}, ${route.value.longitude}")

                        val frag = MapTaskFragment()
                        frag.setArguments(i)
                        val fragmentManager: FragmentManager? = fragmentManager
                        fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(
                            R.id.fmContent
                            , frag
                        )?.commit()

                presenter.onMapTaskClick()


                    }


            address.text = route.value.address
            llRouteContainer.addView(view)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Приложите место откуда вызывается этот фрагмент. Раз метод onViewCreated() вызывается дважды очевидно, что фрагмент открывается дважды

Comment: @SergeiBuvaka Приложил

Answer (score 2):

У вас метод открытия фрагмента находится в цикле:

```
for (route in list.withIndex())
```

Соответственно если в цикле более одного элемента, то вызов фрагмента будет вызываться на каждой итерации.